# Confusion regarding the parent style of an element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, element

Please could somebody explain me the difference between the 2 ways of writing the html code :

CSS file (same for both 1st and 2nd way):

```
.parent{
  color:red;
  font-style: italic;
}
.child_1{
  color:blue;
}
.child_2{
  color:green;
}
```

1st way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    This is the head.
  </head>  
 <body>
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="child_1">
        <p>division1</p> 
     </div> 
     <div class="child_2">
        <p>division2</p>
     </div> 
  </div>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

2nd way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    This is the head.
  </head>  
 <body>
    <div class="parent child_1">
       <p>division1</p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="parent child_2">
       <p>division2</p>
    </div>   
 </body>  
</html>
```

The output for both the ways is exactly the same:

[image]

Please may I know the significance of both the ways and which way is preferred by the developers.

Comment: I don't think there is anything significant. Depends on the developer's way. You can change HTML structure and CSS selectors to your needs as far as they confirm the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

im also a Junior but i'll try to give you way to understand.
Imagine you'r div are boxs.

In your exemple 1:
You can try to change the background-color by typing => background-color: red;
You'r going to see, your 2 child will be affected, by the same background.
In reality, you got 2 box, inside 1

In your exemple 2:
IF you treat the class called parent, you also can modify the background-color. BUT ! your change will affect both of your div by the same way, but you still have only 2 boxs.

Im sorry my english skill isn't perfect, but imagine, each div are boxs. then inside, you can made anothers boxs.